# Find and flat repeated values in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to find values in an np array that are repeated more than x times and set them to 0.

Lets say this is my array:

```
[255,0,0,255,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,0,0]
```

I want to set to 0 all parts that are repeated more than x times.
Lets say, x = 3, the output array will be:

```
[255,0,0,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

If x = 2:

```
[255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Of course, I can loop over the indexes, count them and set to 0, but there's got to be a faster and more efficient way (the purpose is to remove horizontal grids from an image).

Comment: Do you need a faster and more efficient way than a linear runtime and a constant space requirement? Because looping over the indices and counting them and setting to zero is that.

Comment: The image in shape of 6600 X 5100.
A simple loop over it will take a few seconds.
I need it to be done in less than a second.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to "zero" repeated rows in the NxM matrix, or individual elements in the rows? Do you know the spacing of those "horizontal grids"?

Comment: If you want sub-linear runtime (although technically it will still be linear) the only way I see is to just look at each `x/2`th element and only if those are the same inspect the ones in between. Whether that's worth the effort probably depends on your `x`.

Comment: Does it have 0s and 255s only?

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas

```
s = pd.Series(x)
n = 5
s.groupby((s != s.shift()).cumsum()).apply(lambda z: z if z.size < n else pd.Series([0]*z.size)).values

array([255,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  0,   0], dtype=int64)

n = 2
array([255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  0,   0], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to solve this by viewing at your data using a rolling window with length `x+1` and hopsize `1`. If all values in this window are equal, set them all to zero. Rolling windows can easily be done using SciKit image's `view_as_windows()`:

```
import numpy
import skimage

x = 3
data = numpy.asarray([255,0,0,255,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,0,0])
data_view = skimage.util.view_as_windows(data, window_shape=(x + 1,))

mask = numpy.all(numpy.isclose(data_view, data_view[..., 0, None]), axis=1)
data_view[mask, :] = 0

data
# array([255,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0])
```